# List all "duplicate" elements in Tally

Tags: list-manipulation

`Tally[list,test]` can use a custom function `test` to judge if elements are equal. But the output will only give the first element in a group. Is there an option to give all the elements? Or how do I write a custom function to do this?

E.g. Given `{{1,1},{1,2},{1,2,3},{2,3}}`, a tally with test set to head equality would give `{{{1,1},3},{{2,3},1}}`, but I want something like `{{3,{1,1},{1,2},{1,2,3}},{1,{2,3}}}`.

Comment: Possibly GatherBy is what you need but without more specifics I can't say for sure.

Comment: As *Andy* says, seems like a `union` against a `Gather` is what you're after, but you need to give a more useful description.

Comment: See if `Map[{#, Length@#} &, Union /@ Gather[#, <test>]] &@<object>` is what you're after, with <test> being the equality test and <object> the target...

Comment: @ciao Why `Gather` rather than `GatherBy`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I think creation of tests for `Gather` is rather less opaque than with `GatherBy` for neophytes.

Comment: @ciao That's a worthy consideration, but I'll also mention that `GatherBy` is faster when applicable.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Oh, agreed, and OP may very well want *GB* capabilities - but since *Tally* was the source, figured method where test format matches might be easier to grok.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As has been discussed in the comments you can also use `GatherBy`.

```
d = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}};
{Length[#], Sequence @@ #} & /@ GatherBy[d, First]

(*{{3, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}, {1, {2, 3}}}*)
```

Comment: can also be written `{Length@{##}, ##} & @@@ GatherBy[d, First]` for terse-freaks like me. :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm one as well but clearly my kung fu is not as strong as yours :)

Comment: lol -- thanks, I think :-)  ; since you go for this brand of weirdness:  `# ~Prepend~ Length@# & /@ d ~GatherBy~ First`  (or with `{Length@#} ~Join~ #` ...)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard infix is a lovely obfuscator. If only there were short aliases for built in symbols for the purpose of code golf. Accessed via On["Golf"]. Though <<Golf' is probably better.

Answer (score 6):

```
Map[{Length@#, #} &, Union /@ Gather[#, First[#1] === First[#2] &]] &@{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}}

(* {{3, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}}, {1, {{2, 3}}}} *)
```

Do note, you've reversed the order of tally output in your example (which the above follows): tally puts *element* first, then *count*.

If you want *all* elements including duplications, remove the `Union/@`... replace the equality test with seasoning of your choice.

Answer (score 5):

Just a `Reap`/`Sow` variant.

```
test = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}};
Last@Reap[Sow[{##}, #] & @@@ test, _, {Length@#2, #2} &]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}};
```

Using `Query` and `Splice` (new in 12.1)

```
Query[All, {Length, Splice}] @ GatherBy[list, First]
```

{{3, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}, {1, {2, 3}}}

Answer (score 1):

Using the third argument of `GroupBy`:

```
list = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}};

Values@GroupBy[list, First, {Length@#, If[Length@# == 1, #[[1]], #]} &]

(*{{3, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}}, {1, {2, 3}}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is `TallyBy` in the [WFR](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/TallyBy). The *third* argument you can put `Identity` to get all of them:

```
ResourceFunction["TallyBy"][{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}}, First, Identity] // MapApply[Prepend]
{{3,{1,1},{1,2},{1,2,3}},{1,{2,3}}}
```

Note sure if the count and the items should be on the same level, I have a feeling you might have meant:

```
ResourceFunction["TallyBy"][{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}}, First, Identity] // Map[Reverse]
{{3,{{1,1},{1,2},{1,2,3}}},{1,{{2,3}}}}
```

Comment: Please, take a few minutes to write a proper answer. If you don't want to do that, leave that as a comment. Or don't bother at all.